# remembering figure properties in matlab

Tags: matlab, set, figure, imshow

Here is the situation: I am using two displays and the secondary is for displaying the images. What I am trying to do is to make a figure and set its properties (size, position etc.) and then show different images in that figure, without having to redefine the size/position properties each time.

This is the code I use at the moment:

```
hScreen = figure('Position', [screenWidth+1 (screenHeight-1080+1) 1920 1080], 'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);

myImage = imread('test.png');

figure(hScreen), imshow(myImage);
set(gcf, 'position', [screenWidth+1 (screenHeight-1080+1) 1920 1080]);
```

This code works, but the problem is that every time I display an image, I can see the translation/resizing on the screen in a fraction of a second, which is undesirable in my case (or in any case). If I don't use the set() for the images, then, even though I used the figure handle, the image is rendered in an arbitrary position.

How do I make this without needing to reposition/rescale each image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop `imshow` from resizing your figure window by telling it to fit the image to the window. As mentioned in the [excellent documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), the parameter to do that is called `'InitialMagnification'`.

```
hScreen = figure('Position', [screenWidth+1 (screenHeight-1080+1) 1920 1080], 'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5]);

myImage = imread('test.png');
imshow(myImage, 'InitialMagnification','fit');

myImage = imread('test2.png');
imshow(myImage, 'InitialMagnification','fit');
```